# how to insert multiple arrays in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please help me, I'm in trouble with how to insert multiple array in codeigniter.. If I post 2 or 3 arrays, it successfully saves to the database, but if I post more than 3 arrays, the data is not always saved to the database.

Here's my model function :

```php
function add_booking($table,$data) { return $this->db->insert($table,$data); }
```

Here my code :

```php
for($i =0 ; $i < count($data["alamat_tujuans[]"]) ;$i++){
    $tujuan =$data["alamat_tujuans[]"][$i];
    $ddetail = array(
        "id"           =>$delivery_id+$i,
        "address"      =>$tujuan,
        "sku_driver"   =>$data["sku[]"][$i],
        "contact"      =>$data["kontak_penerima[]"][$i],
        "instruction"  =>$data2["instruksi[]"][$i],
        "order_id"     =>$obj[0]->id.'-'.$transid,
        "name"         =>$data["nama_penerima[]"][$i],
        "email"        =>$data["email_penerima[]"][$i],
        "created_date" =>$date,
        "place_name"   =>$data['place_name'],
        "districts"    =>$data['districts'],
        "lat"          =>$data['tujuan1_lat[]'][$i],
        "lng"          =>$data['tujuan1_lng[]'][$i],
        "harga_muatan" =>$data['harga_muatanya[]'][$i],
        "status"       =>$data['status'],
        "provider_id"  =>$_SESSION['logged_in']['provider_id'],
        "city"         =>$data['city']
        );
    $insertData = $this->m_booking->add_booking("delivery_detail", $ddetail);
}
```

Comment: what " the data not all saved in database" mean? is it particulary saved or not saved at all? did it returning an error?

Comment: sometimes saved and sometimes not saved at all

Comment: Have you check on every `$ddetail` within your for loops, that all contains correct data?

Comment: Which data does Not get saved vs which data Does get saved? Is it consistent? Explain more Exactly what happens, vs what you expect to happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer.

```
$data = array(
              array(
                'title' => 'My title',
                'name' => 'My Name',
                'date' => 'My date'
              ),
              array(
                'title' => 'Another title',
                'name' => 'Another Name',
                'date' => 'Another date'
              )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

First, create a multidimensional array using a loop. Once the data is ready to insert into the db, use the function `insert_batch`. The `insert_batch` function will insert all your data at once into the database.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: i have try that, but its still not saved all to database. im so confuse

Comment: I think your array is not formatted properly. Have you tried `print_r` to display the array?

Comment: I have tried that,  the data is succesfully saved into database,  but not all of data..

Comment: @DimasSaputra which data does Not get saved ? Is it consistent?

Comment: thank you all, i have finished my work now. the problem is on a unique column in the table in my database. when I save the data, the data is double. the result of double data is not stored. advice for all, do not forget to issue error messages either from the programming side or from the database side.